# CSS only carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the CSS below so that I don't need the JavaScript snippet to achieve the same desired effect.

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var pageCount = 2;
        var pageWidth = 450;
        $("#pages").css('width', window.innerWidth * pageCount);
        $(".page").css('margin-right', window.innerWidth - pageWidth);
    });
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #pages {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            height: 200px;
            width: 30000px;
            margin-top: -100px;
            left: 50%;
        }

        .page {
            margin-left: -150px;
            width: 300px;
            background: blue;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pages">
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
            <p>This is the first page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
            <p>This is the second page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Page 3</h1>
            <p>This is the third page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can remove this JavaScript and do the same thing in CSS only? Originally I tried playing around with `margin-right: 100%` but couldn't get it to work.

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gfxeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the following CSS:

```
.page {
    counter-increment:section;
    margin-left: -150px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: calc(100%/3 - 300px);
}

#pages {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: calc(100%*3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this is assuming that the page count is always 3. This value is a variable, is there any way to find out how many .page classes there are using CSS?

Comment: @jskidd3 No, CSS does not deal with dynamic amounts of elements well. You may be able to use flexbox, I'm not sure

Comment: I considered the values at CodePen that are different from those you use on your question

Comment: This is what I thought. Your answer will still be selected as best @JoaoAlmeida because it answers the question in hand.

Comment: If you want it with dymanic values you have to check http://lesscss.org/ or http://sass-lang.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution that works with any number of pages and compatible with older browsers (calc is a new CSS feature)

There is however a limitation: the scroll bar is in the pages element. (there is a way to work around this which I will show bellow)

HTML

```
<div id="pages">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="content">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
            <p>This is the first page</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
            <p>This is the second page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Page 3</h1>
            <p>This is the third page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pages {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.page > .content {
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[See Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaKpz)

**If your page will only contain the carousel**, you can replace `#pages` with `body` so that the scroll bar is the *main* scrollbar

[See Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fAxwh)

**By the way**, the CSS in the marked solution is not working. It should be

```
.page {
    ...
    margin-right: calc(100%/3 - 300px);
}
```

[Code Pen for the correction](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ecayi)